# How would I allow my IOS app communicate with my python script

Tags: python, swift, raspberry-pi

I'm developing a product where it shows information about stuff, the product involves a raspberry pi which automatically runs a python program on boot. When it's the users first time using this product they will have to set it up (log into their account etc.). I'd like it for the IOS app to recognize that the product is nearby and allow the user to enter the necessary data (WiFi information, login credentials, etc.) for that product through the app on their phone.

Basically, what I'm trying to ask is that is there any way where I can exchange data between my IOS app and my python program, running on my raspberry pi? I can't do anything through databases since there would be no way of knowing which device needs to connect to what, so I'm guessing something like Bluetooth, just to send the first bits of data (like Wifi information) to get the two linked?

MORE INFO:
An example would be setting up a device like Alexa, how does Alexa connect to your devices to obtain Wifi information so that it can do everything else by itself?

Thanks, Nathan.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prototype a solution quickly, try [Blynk](https://blynk.io/). I've managed to do this type of link using NodeJS and a Raspberry Pi with Blynk previously but their web page suggests you could also use Python or MicroPython. The downside is that, beyond doing basic UI elements, you need to pay for it.

Another approach is to set up a WiFi access point with a web-based system that supports configuration. An example of a device that does this is the [open source energy monitor](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/open-source-energy-monitoring-raspberry-pi/). It might be the case that you can look at how they set up their AP and web server as it is all open source.

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably looking for a free, customizable practical way of doing it, maybe through a HTTP protocol? But thank you.

Comment: I get it now. Hope this other link is more useful.

Comment: I've found this project: https://github.com/schollz/raspberry-pi-turnkey which looks promising, however, it seems more complicated than it needs to be?